# Xcode 6.3 creating new file in wrong place

Tags: ios, xcode, file

last time I updated OS X to El Capitan and installed an update to Xcode. Now it's v. 6.3.2. When I want to add a new file (cocoa touch) on recent or new project, Xcode creates it out of the project. File is phisically in the right direction.

[This screen shows where I put file while adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRbJm.png).

[And this is bad final effect - it should be on "Test Project" with other files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMaX.png).

Before on Yosemite it was all good. What's going wrong?

Comment: Typically, when create a new file, Xcode will attempt to put that file in the same folder as the file you have selected in Project Navigator. Is that not the case here?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not these. I always tried to select folder or file in that folder to which I wanted to add a new file.

Comment: Can you show where is new file placed in finder? Btw, the newest version of XCode is 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. [Screen with file in finder - it's with others, so here it's cool, but in Xcode itself it appears bad.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmbkI.png)

And oh, I didn't know... I'm downloading now 7.2 and I'll post here if something will change.

Comment: And it seems to work properly! Now an added file appears at "Supporting Files" folder, but it can be easily "drag and dropped" at project folder with other files.